# conference_badges #printer should puts the list of badges and room_assignments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

So I am currently getting the following error when I run my code. I used a function inside another function which I believe is the root of the problem but it's been asked to be that way by the instructions.

> Hint: Remember that methods can call other methods. If the return value of assign_rooms is an array of room assignments, how can you print out each assignment? You'll need to iterate over your array of room assignments in order to puts out each individual assignment.

```html
Failures:

  1) conference_badges #printer should puts the list of badges and room_assignments
     Failure/Error: expect($stdout).to receive(:puts).with(line.chomp)
     
       (#<IO:<STDOUT>>).puts("Hello, my name is Edsger.")
           expected: 1 time with arguments: ("Hello, my name is Edsger.")
           received: 0 times
     # ./spec/conference_badges_spec.rb:98:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.02707 seconds (files took 0.28753 seconds to load)
4 examples, 1 failure
```

Which is giving when I run the following code:

```html
def badge_maker(name)
  return "Hello, my name is #{name}."
end

def batch_badge_creator(names)
  greetings = [] # initialize greetings as an empty array
  names.each do |name| # for each name in the names array
    greetings <<  badge_maker(name)# add a greeting for that name
  end
  return greetings # return the array of all greetings, at the end
end

def assign_rooms(speakers)
  greet = []
  speakers.each_with_index{ |speakers, index| greet << "Hello, #{speakers}! You'll be assigned to room #{index+1}!"}
  return greet
  end

def printer(inputOne)
  batch_badge_creator(inputOne)
  assign_rooms(inputOne)

end
```

But I don't get why is not matching the output from Rspec:

```html
 # Question 4
    # The method `printer` should output first the results of the batch_badge_creator method and then of the assign_rooms method to the screen - this way you can output
    # the badges and room assignments one at a time.
    # To make this test pass, make sure you are iterating through your badges and room assignments lists.


    it 'should puts the list of badges and room_assignments' do
      badges_and_room_assignments.each_line do |line|
        # $stdout is a Ruby global varibale that represents the current standard output.
        # In this case, the standard output is your terminal screen. This test, then,
        # is checking to see whether or not your terminal screen receives the correct
        # printed output.
        expect($stdout).to receive(:puts).with(line.chomp)
      end
      printer(attendees)
    end

  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it:

```html
def badge_maker(name)
  return "Hello, my name is #{name}."
end

def batch_badge_creator(names)
  greetings = [] # initialize greetings as an empty array
  names.each do |name| # for each name in the names array
    greetings <<  badge_maker(name)# add a greeting for that name
  end
  return greetings # return the array of all greetings, at the end
end

def assign_rooms(speakers)
  greet = []
  speakers.each_with_index{ |speakers, index| greet << "Hello, #{speakers}! You'll be assigned to room #{index+1}!"}
  return greet
  end

def printer(attendees)
  resultOne = batch_badge_creator(attendees)
  resultOne.each do |x|
    puts x 
  end
  result = assign_rooms(attendees)
  result.each do |x|
    puts x 
  end
end
```